# Resize Splitter (for final user)

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

Main question:
I have a Form that is MDI container and placed a Splitter.

I need that the final user can customize the size of this Splitter. **How?** By default the mouse cursor changes to VSplit but the Splitter is always locked.

Optional question:
This structure/visual layout of this program is identical to the Simatic 7. Example:

[image]

I'm guessing the Splitter is the better option to enable the two panels, the one on the left and the one on the bottom. Right? Or how to get the similar layout of the example?

Comment: verify that the items you have displayed inside the panels that the splitter creates don't have minimum sizes that would prevent it from moving.

Comment: There is nothing inside the splitter yet.

Comment: Just noted splitter rather than split container, I need to read slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a splitContainer over a splitter.  SplitContainer was to [replace splitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter.aspx), but they left it for compatibility.  I find it quite a bit easier to use since it creates the panels for you and gives you better access to the properties you will likely want.

It's quite a bit easier to get to do what you intend without extra work.

You should be able to get that layout with 2 splitcontainers.  Setting one's Orientation property to Horizontal, then placing the other splitcontainer in the top panel.

Simplified Code Sample to display a form:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.TopLevel = false;
SplitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.Show();
```

Comment: I get that. But how to convert one side of panel to host child forms?

Comment: Thanks. But that looks strange. I have to use something like Sanddock to achieve the pretended layout.